# $\cos x + \cos 2x = 1$. Maclaurin series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am required to approximate $\cos (x) + \cos (2x) = 1$ using the first three non-zero terms in the respective Maclaurin series.

I have found the first three non-zero terms for both $\cos (x)$ and $\cos(2x)$:

$[\cos (x)] + [\cos (2x)] \implies [1-(1/2!)x^2+(1/4!)x^4] + [1+(-4/2!)x^2+(16/4!)x^4]$

$\therefore\space 2-(5/2)x^2+(17/24)x^4 = 1 $

When I solve the quartic equation:

$ x = +-1.75...$

$ x=+-0.69... $

When I put either value of $x$ into the original equation, I get $\approx 1.99$. Is there a mistake in my calculations or is this a conceptual error?

Thank you.

Edit: I was using degrees rather than radians. When I use $0.69$ I get $0.96$ which is $\approx 1$. Why is the other value present as a solution but does not $=1$?

Comment: Your solution seems right. Is your calculator perhaps set to degrees rather than radians?

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \cos x gives $\cos x$ compared to cos x which gives $cos x$

Comment: @Micapps, that is almost certainly the explanation. I just asked Google to compute "cos(1.75 deg)+cos(3.5 deg)" and it gave 1.99766838926 for the answer. If the OP isn't rounding up to 1.75, the computed answer woud be slightly smaller.

Comment: To the OP: It might help if you report the values you compute for $\cos(1.75)$ and $\cos(.69)$ (and also $\cos(3.5)$ and $\cos(1.38)$). It looks like some of the computations are being done in degrees and others in radians.

Comment: I think you should use $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x -1$ and solve the quadratic equation in terms of $\cos x$ - only then, go Maclaurin

Comment: @Learner, the result is exactly the same. I just want to know why do I get two values for x when only one satisfies the equation.

Comment: @MugheesAsif: [This Wolfram Alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos(x)%2Bcos(2x)-1,1-5x%5E2%2F2%2B17x%5E4%2F24,x%3D-2..2) illustrates why 0.69 is a good solution but 1.75 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra minus sign in the second term of the $\cos 2x$ series, but you fix it the next line.

When I put $x=0.69$ into the original equation I get about $0.96$, very close to $1$.  When I plug in $1.75$ I get $-1.11$ but the MacLaurin series is not very accurate this far out.